# ZeroDivisionError on a program trying to calculate the sum of user-given integers

Tags: python

I need to write a simple program for my class and I'm stuck on a zero division error. The program has to ask the user to enter a series of non-zero integers, one at a time. If 0 is entered, the program should stop and display the average of all the numbers entered. If only 0 is entered, a message should pop up notifying the user that no numbers were entered. I'm stuck on the condition if only 0 is entered. Any help?

```
number_list = []

def average(mylist):
    return sum(mylist)/len(mylist)

while True:
  number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  if number == 0 and len(number_list) == 0:
    break
    print("No numbers entered.")
  if number == 0:
      break
  number_list.append(number)

 
print("The average of the numbers entered is", average(number_list));
```

Comment: I think you may want to use `continue` instead of `break` and also you need to print before you break\continue

Comment: If the list is empty, don't call the average function.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Like, do you realize what part of is wrong? Are you familiar with [rubber duck debugging](//w.wiki/Uaj)? Stack Overflow isn't a homework help site per se; we're looking for specific questions, not just "here's some code that doesn't work, please help". Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). See also [ask] in general for tips like how to write a good title. Once you get further along in your class, see also [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: How will I know by divisor?     Enter a number: 
    No numbers entered.
    Enter a number: 
    No numbers entered.
    Enter a number: 5
    Enter a number: 5
    Enter a number: 2
    Enter a number:

Answer (score 0):

When 0 is entered, you break out of the loop, and then the print statement outside the loop is executed which calls the average function. Since the average function is called even if the input is 0, you get a ZeroDivisionError. Instead, you can call the average function inside the while loop and then break out of the loop.
Modified code:

```
number_list = []

def average(mylist):
    return sum(mylist)/len(mylist)

while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if number == 0 and len(number_list) == 0:
        print("No numbers entered.")
        break
    if number == 0:
        print("The average of the numbers entered is", average(number_list));
        break
    number_list.append(number)
```

Comment: what about using continue as @monk mentioned, `if number == 0 and len(number_list) == 0:
    print("No numbers entered, please enter different number")
    continue`

Comment: @nisakova I don’t think the OP wants to get input again if 0 is entered the first time. The OP wants to just display a message.

Comment: @nisakova. You cannot used `continue`. Either `break` or `pass` will do.